# issue with json data from api to csv file - seen existing answers but were not relevant

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am getting the data from REST APU in JSON format. I have decoded then writing to pandas dataframe. Later I have been writing to a CSV file  in location. But I end up with an error while writing to CSV. The code snippet is below:

```
response = requests.post(url, authentication)
status_code = response.status_code
print ("response:",status_code)
print ("offset:", offset)
json_data = json.loads(codecs.decode(bytes(response.text, 'utf-8'), 'utf-8-sig'))
#json_data = json.dump(response.text)
print(json_data)
df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(codecs.decode(bytes(response.text, 'utf-8'), 'utf-8-sig')))
delta_file = "C:\\file"
delta_df = data_df.to_csv(delta_file, index=False)
```

It's failing at

> ```
> delta_df = data_df.to_csv(delta_file, index=False)
> ```

Please advise me what went wrong here. Appreciate your quick help.
Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't assign `data_df.to_csv` to a variable. Besides, what error are you getting?

Comment: Also surely you need to add a proper path for `delta_file`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
delta_df = data_df.to_csv(delta_file, index=False)
```

use

```
df.to_csv(delta_file, index=False)
```

There is no `data_df` in your code and there is no sense to save returned value `None` to a variable (`delta_df`).

Comment: This is unlikely to be the source of the error - the OP's code should just assign `None` to `delta_df`. I suppose the real problem is related to the output file.

Comment: @Błotosmętek, read carefully my answer (particularly, the variable's name for dataframe).

Comment: @MariandD Yeah `data_df` is most likely the cause of the error, unless OP is using a jupyter notebook where `data_df` is stored somewhere else. Also `delta_file` looks a bit suspicious. Question worth a downvote

Comment: Right, it seems OP changed his mind about the variable name between lines.

Comment: @MarianD, its not data_df.to_csv, it df.to_csv

Comment: @Blotosmetek, as you said it is an error related to writing to output file.

Comment: @Bhaskar, *"its not data_df.to_csv, it df.to_csv"* — please check out the last line in your question. One of us has probably a problem with his eyes. ;-)